# Why can't we directly set array values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an empty object `myscroll` defined as `var myscroll = {}`. Now I want to add an array property to it. I did it as follows:

```
var myscroll = {}  

myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");  
myscroll.point[1] = getScrollpos("artists");  
myscroll.point[2] = getScrollpos("songs");  
myscroll.point[3] = getScrollpos("beats");  
myscroll.point[4] = getScrollpos("contact");
```

I get the error  `myscroll.point` is not defined. Then I first defined it as `myscroll.point = [];`, then the code worked.

So, Why can't we directly set array values and add that property to an object in javascript? Why do we have to define it first independently?

Comment: How is Javascript supposed to know what exactly `point` is supposed to be if you never initialise it? You *could* add rules to the language to have it somehow infer that, but *explicit is usually better than implicit.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are dealing with object properties, by default you can access any object property and value of that property would be [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) if it wasn't set before. So, by accessing not defined property with index (`myscroll.point[0]`) you are trying to access property `0` of undefined, which is primitive value in javascript and **has no properties**, so you are getting [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError).

As result you can set primitive values to not defined object property, but cannot dial with not defined prop as with object.

Also wanna to point you and explain situation with a little bit similar from first view situations in code below:

```
var obj = []
obj[0] = 10

notDefinedObj[0] = 10 // cause ReferenceError
```

Array is object. In JS you can't modify/add/delete object properties without initialising object before.

That's caused because objects are stored in memory and you can access them by reference.  When you attempt to add new property to it, for instance add new element to list, you are trying to attach property to variable which has no Reference, that's why you are getting [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

**Good Luck!**

Comment: Your answer is fine. I just recalled crockford's similar explanation that accessing a non existing property of an object `obj.myprop` returns `undefined` but accessing that undefined's further properties(or value) `obj.myprop.price` will throw typeError.

Answer (score 3):

With `myscroll.point` you're trying to access a `point` property on the `myscroll` object. But there is no such property on that object. That's why you're getting a `undefined is not an object` error message (or something similar - depending on your browser).

If you're coming from PHP, this might be strange but actually it's much more explicit than the magic involved in the following php snippet for example:

```
$myscroll = [];
$myscroll['point'][0] = getScrollpos("home");  
// ...
```

PHP *automagically* created sub arrays for keys that do not exist.

**Update after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293030/why-cant-we-directly-set-array-values-in-javascript/37293136?noredirect=1#comment62110205_37293136)**

There is a significant difference between `myscroll.mypoint = 5;` and `myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");`.

In the first case your setting the `point` property on `myscroll` to `5` explicitly. But in the second case you're trying to access the `[]` operator (which is an array operator) on a non-existing property `point`. Theoretically Javascript could do the same magic as PHP and create the array *automagically* on the fly, but it doesn't. That's why your getting an error.

It's the same as trying to access a fictitious property `myproperty` on `myscroll.mypoint` like `myscroll.mypoint.myproperty`. This will not work as well, because you're trying to access `myproperty` on `mypoint` which is `undefined` on `myscroll`.

Comment: I don't know php. My question is if I can do `myscroll.mypoint = 5` then why not `myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");`?  if I can access `myscroll.mypoint` then why can't I access `myscroll.point[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `point` property of `myscroll` which is **not defined** (because `myscroll = {}`).

If you will look at the **console** with `myscroll.point`, it will return you `undefined`. Here you were trying to put something in `undefined` so you got ***`TypeError: myscroll.point is undefined`***.

If you define `myscroll` like this:

```
var myscroll = {
         point : []
}
```

Then your code will work and you won't need to define `myscroll.point = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myscroll.point[0] = getScrollpos("home");` can be understood as `Get the first element of the point array inside of myscroll and set it to..`. You can't access the **first element of an non-existing array**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check `typeof` of `myscroll` array variable and then check the `typeof` of `myscroll.point`. You have tried to assign properties of an array, outside of an array. It is empty or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an an empty object and you want to set a new property that holds an array you should do this.

```
var obj = {};
obj['propertyName'] = [];
```

this will put a property with corresponding `propertyName` that holds an array that you can later populate.

if your `getScrolloops()` **returns an array** you can do this

```
obj['propertyName'] = getScrolloops();
```

Idealy in your case you can do this:

```
obj['propertyName'] = [getScrollpos("home"),
     getScrollpos("atrist"),
     getScrollpos("songs"), 
     getScrollpos("beats"),
     getScrollpos("contact")
];
```

**EDIT: Explanation:** Why is your code not working?
As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> You can define a property by assigning it a value.

What you do is trying to define a property by assigning a value to an index of that property. This will not work because you are not assigning a value to the property it's self but to index of a property that dose not exist.

Also i need to mention that you can use both property accessors to achieve that. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) could be a helpful link.